# Getting undefined when i try to access parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access the parameter which is passed to the JavaScript function and alert the value. but when i alert the value i am getting `undefined` in alert. what is wrong i have done here.

**html**

```
<div ng-app="plusminusApp" ng-controller="categorylist">        
    <div class="whitescreen" id="buttons-overlay">
        <div class="icons-container">
            <div class="icons-inside-container">
            <div ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category.picture}}" class="category-icon-thumbnail" onclick="setCategory(this.value);">
                        <img value="{{category.category}}" src="{{category.picture}}">
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
function setCategory(category){
    alert(category)
    document.getElementById('buttons-overlay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Follow the best practices. Use `ng-click`.

Comment: why don't you use angular directive instead of value -> ng-value, src -> ng-src, click -> ng-click() and you haven't utilized ng-model too anywhere where its needed.

Comment: Lots wrong here. A `<div> ` has no value property and you don't use `onclick` in an angular app or search the dom to set style when you can use built in directives like `ng-show`

Comment: update with your json !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a angular's scope value to a function, it must be `ng-` prefixed event. You can't pass scope variable to a function outside of angular context.

```
      <div ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category.picture}}" class="category-icon-thumbnail" ng-click="setCategory(category.picture)">
```

and the function must be in the scope of the controller that means you need to define `$scope.setCategory = function(val){}`

Comment: `this` isn't the element in an `ng-click`, it is the controller. And a div has no value

Comment: what you want to pass to the function?

Comment: @CharanCherry i want to pass the picture URL to the function. and {{category.picture}} contains the string which is picture URL.

Comment: I updated the answer. Have a look. Just pass `category.picture` to the function

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="plusminusApp" ng-controller="categorylist">        
<div class="whitescreen" id="buttons-overlay">
    <div class="icons-container">
        <div class="icons-inside-container">
        <div ng-repeat="category in categories"class="category-icon-thumbnail" >
            <img value="{{category.category}}" src="{{category.picture}}" ng-click="setCategory(category.picture);">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.setCategory = function(val){
     console.log(val)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this to be your json

```
$scope.categories = [{
    'category': 'ABC',
    'picture': 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/22.jpg'
  }, {
    'category': 'ced',
    'picture': 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/13.jpg'
  }]
```

Use the below code

```
$scope.setCategory =function(category) {
    $scope.something=category;
    
    document.getElementById('buttons-overlay').style.display = 'none';
  }



<div ng-app="plusminusApp" ng-controller="categorylist">
    <p>Hello!</p>
    <div class="whitescreen" id="buttons-overlay">
      <div class="icons-container">
        <div class="icons-inside-container">
          <div ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category.picture}}" class="category-icon-thumbnail">
            <button ng-click="setCategory(category.category)"> {{category.category}}
            </button>
            <img value="{{category.category}}" src="{{category.picture}}">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

For simplicity and understanding purpose I have changed the click event from div to button.

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NOHTkPSPIXsrElS5QvnE?p=preview)